# Combining Word vectors and Scalar Features for classification

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, word2vec, text-classification, feature-selection

I am working on a short sentence classification problem where I get the following information

**Input**
Age of the person (1-100)
Gender of the person (Male or Female)
Content of the sentence

**Output**
Label (Type of Content)

To model the sentences I'm using word2vec combined with tfidf. I would also like to add age and gender as features along with the sentence embedding to the classifier. What is the correct way to do this ? Since the embedding is an n-dimensional array and age,gender are scalars. I'm confused about how to add them and visualise the data.

Comment: Any luck finding a solution? I'm dealing with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Word embeddings, as n-dimensional vectors, are just n scalars.

So if for example you have 300-dimensional vectors derived from word vectors, then an age scalar (1-100), then a gender scalar (perhaps 0 or 1), you have 302 dimensions of data for your classifier.

See the [sklearn FeatureUnion transformer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/pipeline.html#feature-union) for an example of concatenating such varied features together. (Some classifiers might perform better if such varied features are scaled to have more similar ranges/distributions.)